# Xcode not generating all required dSYMs even though Build Settings have Debug Information Format = Dwarf with dSYM

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, dsym

Xcode is generating one dsym, which has the name of my app as the filename (e.g. `MyApp.app.dSYM`), but it's not generating the other dsyms with the UUIDs that Firebase is constantly telling me that I'm missing. (e.g. `92248A4B-6CA2-3B54-9787-C007E25C018F.dSYM`)

I've followed the instructions, but something is still wrong. This was working when we were using Fabric, but since we updated to use Firebase directly, nothing is really working properly anymore.

[image: screenshot of firebase error about missing dsyms]

I've followed the instructions on [how to change the Build Settings to make sure the dSYMs get generated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&authuser=0), but my Build Settings were already updated like that when I following the migration instructions from Fabric to Firebase. Here is a screenshot of my Build Settings:

[image: screenshot of Build Settings]

Here is a screenshot of my Run Script Build Phase:

[image: screenshot of Run Script Build Phase]

In the Archive Build Log, the only reference to generating dSYMs is for the one `MyApp.app.dSYM` that I get, but I need the others generated too.

> GenerateDSYMFile
> /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dttbmiamkojuotbcyjgzerxhcqun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM
> /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dttbmiamkojuotbcyjgzerxhcqun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
> (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
> cd /Users/kenny/inaday2/svn-MyApp/trunk/apps/iOS/MyApp
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil
> /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dttbmiamkojuotbcyjgzerxhcqun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
> -o /Users/kenny/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dttbmiamkojuotbcyjgzerxhcqun/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.app.dSYM

Comment: Hello @Kenny Wyland. Were you able to solve this problem? I came across the same thing.

Comment: @Tomas Unfortunately, no. I am constantly having to upload my dsyms to firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Settings look okay, attaching the script I am using and process. Hope these info helps.
[image]
**To have all the dsyms you need to first upload the build to Testflight and then from Tesflight, you need to download the final processed dSYM.zip.**

[image]

**A folder appDsyms.zip will be downloaded, once this is decompressed, you will see list of dSYM's**

Post that use below script to upload the same to crashlytics.
So there are few changes done in Firebase Crashyltics the way dSYM mapped to the build we upload.

Initially, there was a manual option as well to upload but now that's abandoned and the only way by running the script from your terminal.

```
Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp YOUR_PLIST_FULL_PATH -p ios ~/PATH_TO_DSYM_ZIP_OR_FOLDER 

**Example[Below is my working script to upload dSYM to crashlytics]:**

Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols -gsp MY_PRROJECT_NAME/Support/Firebase/Prod/GoogleService-Info.plist -p ios ~/Downloads/appDsyms
```

Comment: this only work if in your app enabled "Enable Bitcode", otherwise dsyms only located on your machine.